# Parsing JSON which contains nested objects

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am newbie to angularjs. I am facing problem while reading JSON which contains nested objects.  I am able to read quantity,rate and amount which are inside cartItems, But unable to read shortDescription  which is inside merchandise.

my JSON is:

```
{
"_links": {
    "search": {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/cartItems/search"
    }
},
"_embedded": {
    "cartItems": [
        {
            "rate": 500,
            "quantity": 1,
            "amount": 500,
            "_embedded": {
                "merchandise": {
                    "shortDescription": "test description1 ",
                    "rate": 500
                }
            },
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/cartItems/801"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "rate": 1000,
            "quantity": 2,
            "amount": 2000,
            "_embedded": {
                "merchandise": {
                    "shortDescription": "test description2",
                    "rate": 1000
                }
            },
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/sportsrest/cartItems/802"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

in my html page i am parsing as:

```
   <tr ng-repeat="cart in cartItems._embedded.cartItems">
                <td>{{cart.quantity}}</td>
                <div ng-repeat="item in cart._embedded.merchandise">
                    <td> {{item.shortDescription}}</td></div>
                <td>{{cart.rate}}</td>
                <td>{{cart.amount}}</td>
            </tr>
```

Anyone help to solve my issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this a typo error? `ng-repeat="cart in cartItems._embedded.cartItems"` there is two times cartItems ...

Comment: cart._embedded.merchandise seems not be an array, so iteration is quite hard, right?

Comment: @DavidVotrubec  First cartItem is where i assigned my JSON data.  $scope.cartItems=json;

Comment: @makallio85 thanks for replay.  yes, So how can i iterare to get shortDescription

Comment: @Ashok kumar See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tr ng-repeat="cart in cartItems._embedded.cartItems">
   <td>{{cart.quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{cart._embedded.merchandise.shortDescription}}</td><td>{{cart.rate}}  </td>
   <td>{{cart.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

cart._embedded.merchandise is not array. To access shortDescrption, do this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="cart in cartItems._embedded.cartItems">
  <td>{{cart.quantity}}</td>
  <td>{{cart._embedded.merchandise.shortDescription}}</td>
  <td>{{cart.rate}}</td>
  <td>{{cart.amount}}</td>
</tr>
```